# how to obtain a value in FCK editor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, fckeditor

i have a problem with FCK editor. i want to obtain a value in the Fck editor, the editor is in a form view and i cant use *Find Control* to reach it. U may ask dude why do u want to obtain value in Fck? because i'm trying to write a Update code and my one field must have FCK editor.

i mean i can use *Find Control* to reach my textboxes in my FormView  like that;

TextBox txt_my_text=(TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("TextBox1");

and then i can use its value like that cmd.Parametres.Add("@param",txt_my_text.Text);

but i wanna reach the Fck Editors value, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it in the same way as with any other server control (ex a textbox).

```
FckEditor editor = new FckEditor(); //You need to create a new instance of the editor
var abcd = editor.Value;
```

What you do is create a new instance of the FckEditor class.

Also probably best to HtmlEncode the value:

```
var abcd = server.Htmlencode( editor.Value;)
```

Comment: the problem is there is no way to create a new instance of the editor. cuz its not like the other objects

Comment: have you included runat="server" on your control?